# Is there any solution in selenium to check whether element is there or not without going to exception

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
try:
    accept_work_order_click_element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='I accept this']")))
    if accept_work_order_click_element:
        accept_wo_click = driver.find_element("xpath", "//span[text()='I accept this']")
        print(accept_wo_click.text)
        # accept_work_order_click_element.click()
        print("Accepted sucessfully")
    else:
        print("No data I accept this")
except Exception as ex:
    print("Wait for element no element present for I accept this : "+str(ex))
```

Is there any solution in webdriver wait that do not go to exception. Why if else is not working for webdriver wait. Or else there is any method which page loads and work the code without exception

Comment: What is your exact usecase? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium For me if the element is not present it is going to the exception. Is there any solution in selenium not to go to exception. Handle by if else or any method

Comment: Define `accept_work_order_click_element` as a list, check for list length > 0, and if True, take the first element from the list : `accept_work_order_click_element[0]`.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Like this...accept_work_order_click_element = list(WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='I accept this Work Order']"))))

Comment: No :). See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63170066/selenium-how-does-webdriverwait-presence-of-all-elements-located-actually-wor

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium, you can check whether an element is present on a web page without using a `try-except` block by using the `find_elements()` method and checking the length of the returned list.

Here's an example:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = Chrome()

# Open the webpage
driver.get("https://www.example.com")

# Find the element
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='example-element']")

if len(elements) > 0:
    print("Element is present")
else:
    print("Element is not present")
```

By checking the length of the list(here, the variable `elements`), you can determine if the element is present or not. If the length is greater than 0, the element is present.

Note that this method doesn't throw an exception if the element is not found, so there is no need for a try-except block.

Comment: What about webdriver wait I need to wait for the element to present in web page.

Comment: you can add the webdriver wait as it is

Comment: It will go to exception.. If element not present

Comment: The following code going to exception if element is not present

Comment: accept_work_order_click_element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='I accept this']")))

Comment: It is not printing empty list if element is not present it is going to exception

Comment: yes, it doesn't work with `WebDriverWait`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using find_element, use find_elements. It returns a list, which is empty if nothing found.

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "wrong")
print(f"{len(elements)}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).